# missing batch operator and have no idea why

Tags: batch-file

I have been programming a text-based pokemon battle and it keeps telling me i have a missing operator. here is the script ive narrowed it down to.

```
set /a attacks=%random% * 3 / 32768 + 1
if %attacks%==1 set /a %ph%==%ph% - %random% * 10 / 32768 + 1
if %attacks%==2 set /a %ph%==%ph% - %random% * 30 / 32768 + 1
if %attacks%==3 set /a %ph%==%ph% - %random% * 50 / 32768 + 1
if %attacks%==3 echo Squirtle used water bolt!
if %attacks%==2 echo Squirtle used Tackle!
if %attacks%==1 echo Squirtle used Water Pulse!
```

any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `set /a %ph%==` you should have `set /a ph=`

Comment: @SomethingDark: This is more significant than it looks. Even if `ph` has a value, numeric or string, the instruction `set /a %var%=` in general seems to be invalid, so you apparently can't use an indirect `set /a`, despite its being logically a valid operation.

Comment: @Magoo: If `var` variable contain a valid variable name, then `set /a %var%=...` is a perfectly valid operation.

Comment: @Aacini: yes. I missed the `==` and was using OP's code for testing. It seems to act as expected with `=`, so OP's question actually contained 2 errors - unwanted indirection (destination is a variable) and incorrect operator as reported by `cmd` - (`==` where `=` is required).

Answer (score 0):

As SomethingDark says, you'll want to use `set /a ph=`. Note that there is one equals sign, which means "gets the value", not two equals signs, which is used with `if` and means "equals?" (as a comparison). Also, what you were doing by setting `%ph%=...` was setting a new variable with the same name of the *value* of the variable `ph`. In other words, if `ph` was set to 1, you were setting a variable named 1 to the result of your math operation. Or, if `ph` was empty, you were probably getting Missing operand (which I think is what you meant to say). Either way, I'm sure that's not what you intended.

This format will work:

```
if %attacks%==1 set /a ph=%ph% - %random% * 10 / 32768 + 1
```

I've got a couple more suggestions.

First, it might be a stylistic choice, but I like to use the mod (`%`) operator with random. It makes it easier to read. Like this:

```
set /a ph=%ph% - %random% %% 10 + 1
```

This (the `%% 10` part) picks a number between 0 and 9, then `+ 1` makes it 1 to 10, using modulo arithmetic (which is, divide by the number, then return the remainder). It's just easier to read IMO. Note that you only need the double `%%` in a batch file. In cmd, just use `%`.

Second, when using comparison with `if`, if one of your operands is ever empty, it will terminate your script. Instead, surround the operands with quotes, so even an empty variable won't break your script. It's not strictly required if your variables are never empty, but might be worth doing.

```
if "%attacks%"=="3" echo Squirtle used water bolt!
```

I hope that helps.